# Exported wallet.dat from bitcoin-qt. Then uninstalled bitcoin-qt. Now the wallet is empty!

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet.dat, lost-bitcoins

Some months ago, I installed bitcoin-qt on Ubuntu, created a wallet and address, then transferred funds to it from MtGox. I let it sync up for over 10 days, but it never fully synced. So I exported a `wallet.dat` file, then uninstalled bitcoin-qt.

Today, I installed MultiBit and imported the `wallet.dat` file. It is empty. It has one address which shows no transactions or balance on blockchain.info. The wallet in bitcoin-qt had several addresses.

What happened? Is there anything I can do to restore the files containing my bitcoin?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. What I had to do is delete the copy of the blockchain and let the newly installed bitcoin qt download and sync from scratch. All was good after that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you re-install bitcoin-qt and open the wallet again? Maybe all the addresses are there.

What about your account at Mt. Gox? If you transferred the coins from Mt. Gox, you should be able to look up the transaction on blockchain.info. Either the sending address still has the coins, or the receiving address does.