# Does an empty bitcoin.conf file cause my Bitcoin-core wallet to have a balance of 0?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin.conf

I need help with THE bitcoin -qt logiciel (V23.0) ! two questions : what is normally in bitcoin-conf please!!
and why, this file has no script and does not see the transactions, why? please ?! why ??
is a link that : bitcoin.conf = 0 bytes AND not seeing transactions on my wallet .dat type file opened and synced to the blockchain!?
Thank you, if we check the coins are in the wallet (and auxiliary on various keys privates)  who help me I render thanks !! very very !!

Answer (score 3):

> **what is normally in bitcoin-conf**

It is normal for it to be empty (0 bytes).

It only has contents if you deliberately change the configuration.

---

> **[I am] not seeing transactions on my wallet.dat type file [which was] opened and synced to the blockchain**

If the blockchain is not *fully* synced you will see the "catching-up" icon at bottom right of the bitcoin-qt window: [image: ![catching up]]

If you have upgraded Bitcoin-core, you should check that a copy of your old `wallet.dat` is in the place expected by bitcoin-core. For example, in Windows 10 a default location would be `%AppData%\Roaming\Bitcoin\wallets`

---

> **is [there] a link [between] bitcoin.conf = 0 bytes AND not seeing transactions on my wallet**

No.

In *ordinary* use of Bitcoin core, there is no link between these two observations.

If you had previously changed the bitcoin.conf to relocate wallet.dat when using an older version of Bitcoin core but did not follow a normal upgrade process that preserves bitcoin.conf then there could be a causative link. I would check one of my backups to see the previous contents of bitcoin.conf.

---

Also see

- [Wallet balance zero after restoring wallet.dat](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/5690/13866)
- [Exported wallet.dat from bitcoin-qt. Then uninstalled bitcoin-qt. Now the wallet is empty!](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/17924/13866)
- [How do I import a private key into Bitcoin-Core?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/5941/13866)